# How can i match user ipaddress from my mysql database ip lookup table?

Tags: mysql, .net, ip-address

I have network addresses of ipv4 and ipv6 in table and want to calculate its ranges in columns from_ip ,to_ip  in ipaddress and in bigint numeric form of both ipv4 and ipv6 networks so that i can easily query with entity framework with considering performance.

Tried with IPNetwork2 nuget lib with with query

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
var result = await bContext.IpLookups.Join(dbContext.CountryLookups,
    ipv4 => ipv4.GeoNameId,
    country => country.GeoNameId,
    (ipv4, country) => new { Ipv4 = ipv4, Country = country })
    .Where(n => IPNetwork.Parse(n.Ipv4.Network).Contains(ipAddress))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But where clause  doesn't get translated to SQL since the ORM can't interpret "Contains" into SQL
it's loading the entire table into memory (both iplookup and country_lookup) every time the query is ran then it's running the where clause in memory
I captured the actual SQL query in MySQL

```
SELECT `ipv4`.`id`, `ipv4`.`geoname_id`, `ipv4`.`is_anonymous_proxy`, `ipv4`.`ipv4`, `ipv4`.`is_satellite_provider`, `ipv4`.`network`, `ipv4`.`registered_country_geoname_id`, `ipv4`.`represented_country_geoname_id`, `country`.`id`, `country`.`continent_code`, `country`.`continent_name`, `country`.`country_iso_code`, `country`.`country_name`, `country`.`geoname_id`, `country`.`is_in_european_union`, `country`.`locale_code`
FROM `iplookup` AS `ipv4`
INNER JOIN `country_lookup` AS `country` ON `ipv4`.`geoname_id` = `country`.`geoname_id`
```

Now trying to make two columns from_ip and to_ip so that i can query from them without joining
Expecting output:
Add low and high IP columns to iplookup
write query to generate the values for low and high using CIDR
add indexes to low and high
update query in code to match ip address between low and high values
from_ip | to_ip
1.0.0.0 | 1.0.0.255  network ipv4 1.0.0.0/24
2001:200:: | 2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff   network ipv6 2001:200::/32

I want to match and user ipaddress from my database lookup table with the best practice.
lookup contains millions of records

Comment: `BIGINT` is unnecesarily big for IPv4 and too small for `IPv6`.

Answer (score 0):

For range testing of IPv4 addresses, I suggest converting to `INT UNSIGNED` (32 bits).

For range testing of IPv6 addresses, I suggest converting to `BINARY(16)` using an algorithm that will suitably expand `::` as needed.  That will be compact (16 bytes) and efficient for comparison.

`VARCHAR(15)` and `VARCHAR(39)`, respectively, are suitable for the string representation.  (Suggest `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci`)

More discussion here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges  (See the discussion of representation.)  Some of that document is superceded by the following:

MariaDB has an `INET6` *datatype* as of 10.5:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/

MySQL has `INET6_ATON()` and `INET6_NTOA()` for converting IPv6 addresses; `INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()` for converting IPv4 addresses.

Comment: for ipv6 these functions throwing error Error Code: 1411. Incorrect string value: `iplookup`.`network`' for function inet6_aton network is of text datatype containing the ipv4 and ipv6 cidr...

Comment: i have one table for both cidr 1pv4 and ipv6 with bit isipv4 0/1. able to convert the ipv4 address with inet6_Aton and inet6_ntoa but not ipv6 cidr can you give me the sql query to do that

Comment: Let's see the expression that got the 1411.  Include values used.